# SpringBatch: Test a JobExecutionListener

Tags: testing, listener, spring-batch, jobs

I got a `JobExecutionListener` as follows:

```
public class JobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(final JobExecution jobExecution) {
        // do some work with the jobExecution
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(final JobExecution jobExecution) {
        // do some work with the jobExecution
    }
}
```

I want to write a test for my JobListener and i am wondering myself if i need to mock the JobExecution. Do you think that will be ok, or is there another nice solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring batch comes with a nice testing framework.
Add the following to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>   
 <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you want to unit test this class, you may use the org.springframework.batch.test.MetaDataInstanceFactory to create a job context 
e.g.

```
JobListener jobListener = new JobListener ()
//Create a JobExecution (You have 6 overloaded methods choose the one you like)
JobExecution jobExecution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createJobExecution(..);
jobListener.beforeJob(jobExecution);
jobListener.afterJob(jobExecution);
```

If you want to make this into an integration test write a snippet job xml that contains some mocked job and use the org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils
For more information see http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html