# Spring Batch error (A Job Instance Already Exists) and RunIdIncrementer generates only once

Tags: spring-batch

i'm using Spring Batch & Quartz to read from database table and write in another table. the database is Oracle and it is c3p0

the problem is each job must have a unique parameters, I tried [RunIdIncrementer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/RunIdIncrementer.html) and I tried this code:

```
public class JobRerunner implements JobParametersIncrementer {

    @Override
    public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) {
        System.out.println("got job parameters: " + parameters);
        if (parameters==null || parameters.isEmpty()) {
            return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("run.id", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
        }
        long currentTime = parameters.getLong("run.id",System.currentTimeMillis()) + 1;
        return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("run.id",currentTime).toJobParameters();
    }

}
```

but I get the same problem, the run.id is generated only once, and when the job is ran for the second time it has no parameters at all and the third time also (the second and third run JobParameter = null so (Job Instance Already Exists)

job context

```
<batch:job id="readyReqPoolJob" restartable="true">
    <batch:step id="readyReqPoolStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="readyReqPoolReader" writer="readyReqPoolWrtiter"
                commit-interval="100" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>


<!-- ======================================================= -->
<!-- 6) READER -->
<!-- ======================================================= -->
<bean id="readyReqPoolReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="select * from SF_ILA_Ready_Request_Pool" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="ReadyReqPoolRowMapper" />
</bean>
<bean id="readyReqPoolWrtiter"
    class="com.housekeepingservice.readyrequestpoolarchive.ReadyReqPoolArchiveWriter" />


<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass"
        value="org.springframework.batch.sample.quartz.JobLauncherDetails" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="jobName" value="readyReqPoolJob" />
            <entry key="jobLocator" value-ref="jobRegistry" />
            <entry key="jobLauncher" value-ref="jobLauncher" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <bean id="cronTrigger"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
            <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
            <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

main context:

```
<import resource="classpath:spring/batch/config/readyReqPoolContext.xml"
<import resource="classpath:spring/batch/config/jdbc.commons.xml" />
    <!-- 1) USE ANNOTATIONS TO CONFIGURE SPRING BEANS -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.housekeepingservice" />


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />

    <!-- 3) JOB REPOSITORY  -->

    <bean id="jobRepository" 
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 4) LAUNCH JOBS FROM A REPOSITORY -->
    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />

    <bean id="jobExplorer"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
        <bean name="jobParamatersIncrementer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer">
    </bean>
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] springConfig = { "spring/batch/config/mainContext.xml" };

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                springConfig);
        JobRerunner rerun = new JobRerunner();

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");

        Job readyRequestPoolJob = (Job) context.getBean("readyReqPoolJob");


        try {


            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();
             JobExecution execution2 = jobLauncher.run(readyRequestPoolJob, rerun.getNext(jobParameters));

            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution2.getStatus());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    }

}
```

log (checkout the job incetance parameters in the first run and the second run):

```
17:00:27,053  INFO SimpleJobLauncher:132 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=readyReqPoolJob]] launched with the following parameters: **[{run.id=1393855226339}]**
17:00:27.085 [Timer-0] DEBUG org.quartz.utils.UpdateChecker - Checking for available updated version of Quartz...
17:00:27,272  INFO SimpleStepHandler:135 - Executing step: [readyReqPoolStep]
17:02:08,791  INFO SimpleJobLauncher:135 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=readyReqPoolJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1393855226339}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
17:10:00.005 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Calling execute on job DEFAULT.jobDetail
17:10:00,008  INFO JobLauncherDetails:69 - Quartz trigger firing with Spring Batch jobName=readyReqPoolJob
17:10:00,036  INFO SimpleJobLauncher:132 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=readyReqPoolJob]] launched with the following parameters: **[{}]**
17:10:00,059  INFO SimpleStepHandler:135 - Executing step: [readyReqPoolStep]
```

Answer (score 4):

Set step `allowStartIfComplete` flag to `True`

Comment: Simple and to the point solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To lunch a job with job Incremater you need two things

1. Attach the RunIdIncremater to your job.
2. Use a launcher that is aware of the usage Incremater.

I do not see any need for your own implementation just use the existing one.
**Attach the RunIdIncremater to your job.**

```
<batch:job id="readyReqPoolJob" incrementer="runIdIncrementer" restartable="true">
</batch:job>
<bean id="runIdIncrementer" 
class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer"/>
```

**Use a launcher**
To launch it you should use one of the following:
**Option 1:** CommandLineJobRunner with the –next option see the [API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html)

**Option 2:** User JobOperator

```
<bean id="jobOperator"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
        <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer" />
</bean>
```

in the code

```
jobOperator.startNextInstance(jobName)
```

**Option 3:** In Junit you can use JobLauncherTestUtils.
Note that it has it’s own id Incremater and will ignore the one you use
see also the following answer [SpringBatch: Test a JobExecutionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096617/springbatch-test-a-jobexecutionlistener/22140263#22140263)

Comment: I already tried that, same problem occurs then I removed it & used my own incrementer

Comment: I added some more details I hope that it will be more clear now.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I did it & the result: first when I run it I get "Bad SQL Grammar Exception" then the job runs with no parameter twice, first one success second one "Job Instance is Already  exists and is complete" 

is there any special configuration for Job Repository and the other beans ?

Comment: The CommandLineJobRunner  should replace you main code e.g.
java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner mainContext.xml readyReqPoolJob -next

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter called 'timestamp' for example or - if you want to use `run.id` - set [Job.jobParametersIncrementer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/AbstractJob.html#setJobParametersIncrementer%28org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersIncrementer%29) with your `jobParamatersIncrementer` bean definition.

Comment: could you clarify more please?

Comment: To make every execution unique add a new identify job parameter called 'timestamp' (for example) to your current job parameters and set it with `new Date().getTime()` so no collision with old job execution should happens

Comment: you mean like:

JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

Comment: I am already trying to give each job a unique parameter the problem is the unique parameter is generated only once then the job executes with null parameters, I even tried JobLauncherTestUtils class and its method getUniqueJobParameters() but the same problem occurs, you mentioned the bean definition, is there any settings regarding the bean definition to fix this problem?